# Blocking/Nonblocking with Delay

Tags: verilog

I am now confused by one piece of Verilog Code, its kind of testing the blocking or non-blocking assignment features that combination with Delay model.

The code is below [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Was):

```
module cl_tb;
  reg x,y,z;

  initial begin
    x = 2;
    #4;
    y <= #9 x;
    x = 1;
    #50 $stop;
  end

  initial begin
    $monitor("%0t,%d,%d,%d",$time,x,y,z);
  end

  always @(x,y) begin
    z = # 2 x+y;
  end 
endmodule
```

By hand-calculation according to the Verilog Stratified Event, I could get the result
Time: X value, Y value, Z value below:

```
 0: 2,x,x
 2: 2,0,2 
 4: 1,0,2
 6: 1,0,1
13: 1,2,1
15: 1,2,3
```

However, the simulation result is :

```
 0,0,x,x
 4,1,x,x
13,1,0,x
15,1,0,1
```

I am wondering why the always@(x,y) was not triggered at timeslot 2 and 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared x,y,z as 1 bit. So When setting to 2 your only getting the LSB (bit 0) of 2'b10.

If your just testing the delay modelling then use integer instead of reg.

```
integer x,y,z;
```

You should now see values higher than 1. An updated example on [EDA playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Nw2).

If I update your monitor to a display

```
initial begin
  forever begin
    $display("%3t: %2d,  %2d,  %2d",$realtime, x, y, z);
    #2;
  end
end
```

I get the same result nothing at `#2` but if we change the loop delay to `#1` it looks like it is working as expected. I have tried forcing the `` `timescale `` but that does not look to fix the issue.

```
# KERNEL:   0:  2,   0,   0
# KERNEL:   1:  2,   0,   0
# KERNEL:   2:  2,   0,   2 //<-- update at time 2
```

NB: Automatic Sensitivity lists help minimize RTL to gate simulation mismatch.

```
always @(a,b) begin
```

becomes

```
always @* begin
```

Comment: you are correct,  The width mismatch and uninitialized x,y,z value leads to the observation problem. \n Also, only modify that part could get the simulation result that same with the hand calculation. The $monitor is enough to capture the "final" result at certain simulation step, since it is in the inactive region. So no forever + $display is not needed I think :) Thanks again for your time